# Rails: Trying to add search function - keep getting "no route matches"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controllers

I'm trying to implement a simple search function for my Rails app by following [this guide](https://we.riseup.net/rails/simple-search-tutorial). I am trying to allow users to search for animal by name.

Here's my current code:

*controllers/animals_controller.rb*

```
class AnimalsController < ApplicationController
  def search
    @animal = Animal.search(params[:search])
  end    
end
```

Here's my *views/animals/index.html.erb*

```
<%= form_tag :controller => 'animals', :action => 'search', :method => 'get' do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :id => 'search_field' %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %> 
<% end %>
```

And here is the error I keep getting:

> No route matches {:action=>"search", :controller=>"animals",
>   :method=>"get"}

I don't understand why this isn't working. I have the search function defined in the animal_controller.rb. Can anyone point out why the search function may not be working?

Comment: Did you define the route in your `routes.rb` file? You should probably add the `routes.rb` file content to your question.

Comment: I tried adding
get ‘animals/search’, to: ‘animals#search’, but that isn't working either.

Comment: You should really add your `routes.rb` to your question. And, run `rake routes` in your console to see what you have defined.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the guide you are following, creating a `GET /search` route was never mentioned. You can define the route in `config/route.rb` with this

```
resources :animals do
  get :search
end
```

or

```
get search: "animals#search"
```

Comment: Don't assume that OP hasn't defined a route for the request unless we know how the _routes.rb_ looks.

Comment: Yes. You are right. I updated my answer. Thanks. I don't have enough reputation to clarify posts yet. So I based it on the given guide and error message.